# How to keep close a sub-menu under homepage?

Tags: javascript, css, sub-menu

I am facing an issue in the Avada vertical menu when the homepage is opened. Please note that all "Home", "Company profile" and "Servizi" link to the same page (the homepage).

The sub-menu under "Servizi" is already opened while I would prefer it was closed by default, and that it could be opened simply by hovering "servizi", as it works properly when you try hovering "Servizi" from both "Clienti" and "Contatti".

I am pretty sure there is an option in Avada/WP to do that, or otherwise by adding some JS code, but I really have no idea how to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you have to set `hidden` attribute to the sub menu.

**CSS**

```
#wrapper .fusion-vertical-menu-widget.left .menu .sub-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

to toggle display on the menu on hover over servizi, you can add jQuery hover to the menu item.

**jQuery**

```
var subMenu = jQuery("#wrapper .fusion-vertical-menu-widget.left .menu .sub-menu");

jQuery("#menu-item-12049").hover(function(){
   subMenu.show();
  }, function(){
   subMenu.hide();
});
```

**Note:** You should change the class values to more appropriate values, these are just extracted from what I saw, but probably a good idea to get better css selectors

Comment: Hello Vishwa, thank you a lot for your help!
Unfortunately I don't know jQuery very well... So, I read on the Internet that I need to include jQuery in functions.php which I did typing "function include_jQuery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'include_jQuery');"

Comment: is this solves your problem? if so, you can accept/upvote the answer so it'd be helpful to someone else

Comment: But it still doesn't work. I changed your #wrapper .fusion... into "ul.sub-menu"
Doing this will hide the sub-menu as you can see on the website, just if I write display: none !important, but the jQuery doesn't re-open the sub-menu

Comment: try `$("#menu-item-12049").hover(function(){alert("hover")}` to see whether hover event works.  To include jQuery, add following to the functions.php in your theme folder. 


`function add_jq_theme() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_jq_theme' );`

Comment: jQuery seems to have some effects now, the sub-menu now remains close (and does not open on hover) in every page, even "clienti" and "contatti" XD
The important thing, however, the alert function, doesn't work yet. So it seems that jQuery is properly included now, which is great, but probably the function code is not considered. I copied your alert function code in Avada Theme Options, in the box "Space before </head>" where I can put some JS code, in a mandatory <script> tag. Do you think it's a wrong place?

Comment: I'm not familiar with avada theme. however I thing this `$("#menu-item-12049")`section could be the problem. try to find css selector for servizi

Comment: *update* I missed bracket and a semicolon in `$("#menu-item-12049").hover(function(){alert("hover")});` Try it now. anyway, when I tried using code in my answer, in browser console, it worked. I'll update my answer a little bit more. try it too

Comment: Thank you again Vishwa! I just left a new reply! Basically I managed to get the alert function work, so I tried to use the original function you posted, that works but only for the homepage now, reversing the original situation

Comment: may be where you add the jQuery code would only be loading in the homepage? did you try the alert in other pages? what could be the result?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in writing my reply: I'd like the sub-menu remained opened always (not only by hovering) only when you are on a sub-menu single page (like "organizzazione", but not for the main pages

Comment: to achieve that, take the body classes (class values on <body> tag ) on pages you need to hide the sub menu on load. to do that, use either view source or browser inspector tool. then update `jQuery("#menu-item-12049").hover(function(){`with `jQuery("`body.your-page-bodyclass #menu-item-12049").hover(function(){`   when use select body class choose something like *page-id-368* so it would be something like *body.page-id-368*

Comment: Hey Vishwa! I solved the issue by adding a display:block !important to every sub-menu item so that the jquery doesn't change anything for those. I tried using the body class and it works but since all of my main pages need the hover feature, keeping the sub-menu closed by default, I should add the body class of every main page without any benefit.

Thank you a lot Vishwa for your help! I would have never managed to fix it by myself

Comment: glad to be a help. good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

So, now it works perfectly as I would like when you hover "servizi"! The only problem is for the sub-menu single pages, where the sub-menu should remain opened always, like it did before

This is the code used currently in avada theme options:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var subMenu = jQuery("#wrapper .fusion-vertical-menu-widget.left .menu .sub-menu");
jQuery("#menu-item-12049").hover(function(){
subMenu.show();
}, function(){
subMenu.hide();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: please take a note at my last comment